# Is it correct to use "meeting" this way?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, style

Is it correct to use "meeting" this way? or it should be replaced by **holding**?

The authorities in our country want to hire people with experience and beyond the average qualities, as is the case with her. On the one hand, she speaks English but also has working experience with the government, which are characteristics of high demand in our country with few professionals **meeting** them.

Comment: We hold characteristics, we meet demands. We can even use the word [...] 'possessing' them. Also, __on one hand__, no need of the definite article.

Comment: Professionals can meet standards or requirements.  They have or possess characteristics. (I disagree about **holding characteristics). Prefer **with exceptional qualities**.